# for loop in Julia - iterating over an entire index

Tags: for-loop, indexing, julia

I'm having trouble getting Julia to go through all the numbers in a matrix:

```
A = [1 -2 3; -4 -5 -6; 7 -8 9]
```

I want to turn all of the negative numbers into a positive 3

I tried:

```
for i=A[1:end]
  if i<0
    A[i] = 3
    i += 1
  end
  return (A)
end
```

I've tried moving the i+=1 to various positions. But still it's not changing anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `enumerate`:

```
julia> A = [1 -2 3; -4 -5 -6; 7 -8 9]
3×3 Array{Int64,2}:
  1  -2   3
 -4  -5  -6
  7  -8   9

julia> for (i,v) in enumerate(A)
       if v < 0
       A[i] = 3
       end
       end

julia> A
3×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  3  3
 3  3  3
 7  3  9
```

or `eachindex`:

```
julia> A = [1 -2 3; -4 -5 -6; 7 -8 9]
3×3 Array{Int64,2}:
  1  -2   3
 -4  -5  -6
  7  -8   9

julia> for i in eachindex(A)
       if A[i] < 0
       A[i] = 3
       end
       end

julia> A
3×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  3  3
 3  3  3
 7  3  9
```

You can find details about those functions in interactive help in Julia REPL.

Comment: Do you find `A[A.<0] = 3;` satisfactory?

Comment: Maybe `replace!(x->x<0 ? 3 : x, A)`.

Comment: BTW, `A[A.<0] = 3` won't work, though `A[A.<0] .= 3` will. But it's 60x slower than `replace!`.

Comment: `replace!` is a very nice functional programming approach. I thought @hhillman231 wanted to learn how to properly use loops in Julia as this is what question title indicated.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński  The dual answers with both `enumerate` and `eachindex` I found helpful.  Not sure I remember seeing `eachindex` before.

Comment: @DNF `A[A.<0] = 3` worked with Julia v0.6.4 which didn't have `replace!`.  Another good reason to upgrade.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's true. It does not work on v1.0, though.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `eachindex`, you can iterate over a range, in this case the range of indices, like in MatLab.

```
for i = 1:length(A)
    if A[i] < 0
        A[i] = 3
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another alternative. We can use `foreach`.

```
A = [1 -2 3; -4 -5 -6; 7 -8 9]
foreach(j->A[j]=A[j] < 0 ? 3 : A[j], 1:1:length(A))
```

which yields to

```
3×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  3  3
 3  3  3
 7  3  9
```

as desired.